# Haxe flash packages to HTML5 output?

Tags: javascript, html, haxe

I built a Haxe/OpenFL project using many of the flash packages, ie flash.display.* stuff as well as the events and more.  Which exported to HTML5 just fine.

Now I am told I can not use OpenFL, and I need to stick to Haxe built in libraries.

Without rewriting most of my code is there a way to get the flash packages to export to JS or HTML5?

If I switch to a Javascript target I get, you cannot access the flash package while targeting cross ...

And there is not HTML5 output option without OpenFL ("nme").

Any suggestions, or do I just need to rewrite everything in pure Haxe/JS?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to compile to JS using openfl, replacing packages flash.display... with openfl.display... should not be necessary but may help you figuring the problem or will eventually work as it should.

Also make sure you use the command "openfl test html5" in your application.xml folder to compile, if you don't have this file, then grab it from any openfl example, what it does is calling the haxe compiler with the proper arguments and configurations for the openfl project.

Comment: Thanks for the response TiagoLr but that is exactly what I did and what I need to move away from.  I am trying to get rid of the OpenFL library and still export to HTML5.

Comment: Depending on how much your codebase depends on the flash API, that could take some time / effort. Why are you trying to get rid of OpenFL in the first place? Sounds like you depend on it for at least rendering.

Comment: I agree with @Gama11, it sounds odd to get rid of OpenFL, then expect all the code to be HTML5 ready just like that… OpenFL is an abstraction layer, get rid of it and you have to do all the work for yourself.